# Apache Kafka StartUp Error - Invalid value 3.0-IV1 for configuration message.format.version

Tags: apache-kafka

I have got Apache Kafka installed on Microsoft WSL (Linux Distribution Ubuntu 18) and all of a sudden we are getting this error on our local machine when starting kafka.

We tried deleting tmp\kafka-logs as well but it still doesn't work. I have checked kafka server.properties file as well and can't find anything there either. We also downloaded a higher version of kafka and tried running that and still same error. So it looks like some config is not right outside Kafka?

**org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 3.0-IV1 for configuration message.format.version: Version `3.0-IV1` is not a valid version**

```
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,421] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,421] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,542] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 3.0-IV1 for configuration message.format.version: Version `3.0-IV1` is not a valid version
        at kafka.api.ApiVersionValidator$.ensureValid(ApiVersion.scala:361)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:484)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:468)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:142)
        at kafka.log.LogConfig.<init>(LogConfig.scala:71)
        at kafka.log.LogConfig$.fromProps(LogConfig.scala:314)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$getLogConfigs$2(KafkaZkClient.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.getLogConfigs(KafkaZkClient.scala:308)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:1090)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:273)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,544] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,546] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,660] INFO Session: 0x1000006a11f0002 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,660] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000006a11f0002 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,661] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-08-10 12:24:12,662] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:13,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:13,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:13,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,421] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,421] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,422] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,429] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,430] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2023-08-10 12:24:14,430] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I was able to solve it by deleting these two folders (`kafka-logs` and `zookeeper`). It turns out some of the topics had some badly formatted data. But just note that by doing that you could loose all your topics. In my case it was ok because it's my local environment and I can just recreate it.

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\tmp\kafka-logs
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\tmp\zookeeper
```